# Postgresql showing different behavior on two environment having exactly same configuration

Tags: postgresql-13

We have two environment staging and production. For Database service we are using AWS RDS(postgresql).

```
SELECT * 
FROM addressfabric_v2_2022_7 
WHERE ST_Intersects(ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((-75.7891846 45.2530176,-75.2783203 45.2568822,-74.9981689 45.3688422,-75.0750732 45.5613573,-75.7397461 45.6113035,-75.7891846 45.2530176))',4326),geometry)  
limit 20 offset 180
```

We are getting different response for above query on staging and production. Data and RDS configuration on both environments are exactly same.

**Query Plan:Staging**

[image]

**Query Plan:Production**

[image]

Same query is behaving differently on staging and production environment.

I have also checked the value of "max_parallel_workers_per_gather". On both environment it is 4.

Comment: Execution plans are better shared as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) generated using `explain (analyze, buffers, format text)` Screen shots of some graphical representation simply hide way too many details.

Answer (score 2):

Since you specify no `ORDER BY` in your queries, the DBMS is free to return rows in any order it sees fit, so it's no surprise you get different results. You might even get different results in the *same* environment now and then.

If you want deterministic results, use a deterministic order.